# How to update based on original values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-update

I'm trying to do a very simple update of table where I want to substitute one string for another in a large table. I'm trying to do it in batches because the table has hundreds of millions of rows.

But I need to replace the string differently depending on what was there, but still meet the requirement of the batch number being in the most recent timestamp.

I don't want to run 5 different scripts separately.

I've gotten this far, but I don't know how to apply the update correctly depending on what was there originally.

Any ideas on how to do it efficiently?

```
DECLARE @batchsize bigint = 1000;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (@batchsize) Table1
    SET Row1 = 'To1'  -- want to set To2, To3, To4, To5, etc. depending on what was in there already
    FROM (SELECT TOP (@batchsize) Id
    FROM Table1 
    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) tto
    WHERE Table1.Row1 in ('From1', 'From2', 'From3', 'From4', 'From5') AND Table1.Id = tto.Id;

    if @@ROWCOUNT < @batchsize
    BEGIN
        PRINT('All Done');
        BREAK;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a CASE expression?

Comment: You're not really describing your business logic in enough detail. Can you tell us more about what you mean by: `I need to replace the string differently depending on what was there`

Comment: **Careful**, if the new updated values overlap with the old previous ones, then it will never finish. If not, a CASE can solve the replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this should do it:

```
SET Row1 = CASE 
  WHEN Row1 = 'From1' THEN 'To1' 
  WHEN Row1 = 'From2' THEN 'To2' 
  etc
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for a `case` expression?

```
   UPDATE TOP (@batchsize) Table1
     SET Row1 = (CASE table1.Row1
                     WHEN 'From1' THEN 'To1'
                     WHEN 'From2' THEN 'To2'
                     WHEN 'From3' THEN 'To3'
                     WHEN 'From4' THEN 'To4'
                     WHEN 'From5' THEN 'To5'
                 END)
     FROM (SELECT TOP (@batchsize) Id
           FROM Table1 
           ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
          ) tto
     WHERE Table1.Row1 in ('From1', 'From2', 'From3', 'From4', 'From5') AND
           Table1.Id = tto.Id;
```